# Min-max date issue in date-time picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [smDateTimeRangePicker](https://github.com/mominsamir/smDateTimeRangePicker) to show a date-time picker dialog.
Along with this, I am using `moment.js` for date manipulation. For the date picker, I set `minDate` and `maxDate` in my controller as follows:

```
$scope.minDate = moment().subtract(5, 'months').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
$scope.maxDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I want to allow the user to select a date between today and 5 months before today's date.

But when I assign these values to the date-time picker, it is only allowing me to select today's date. All other dates are disabled.

Is there anything that I am missing or doing wrong?
Here's the plunker to an example which reproduces this issue: [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jjs1rPiC5F6td3FNXld0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the format of `minDate` and `maxDate` to match the `format` attribute

```
$scope.minDate = moment().subtract(5, 'months').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
$scope.maxDate = moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

and you haven't used expression binding for attributes in your template like below

```
max-date="{{maxDate}}"
min-date="{{minDate}}"
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mbND4C?p=preview)

Comment: Oh that was dumb of me. I forgot to add the curly braces! Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped and don't forgot to match the date format of min,max dates with format attribute

Comment: In my application, I have two date selectors, one for start date and one for end date. What I want is, for `end date` the min-date should be the date selected in `start date`. But I am not sure, why it is not able to take it. Can you please have a look at it? Here's the plunker for that: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jjs1rPiC5F6td3FNXld0?p=preview